# How do you delete trailng white space in emacs?

Tags: emacs

I have a text file that has fixed length lines, padded by trailing spaces like:

```
hello world                 ↩
this is some other line     ↩
x                           ↩
```

and I want to remove the trailing spaces on each line so it looks like

```
hello world↩
this is some other line↩
x↩
```

Is it possible to write an emacs macro that can solve this?

Edit: the lines can have any arbitrary number of spaces in it before the trailing spaces at the end, so

```
hi     world                ↩
```

can be a valid line in this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emacs has the built-in `fixup-whitespace` (`M-space`), which shrinks more than one space to only one space:

```
hello      world         ↩
                    ^
                  cursor 

M-x fixup-whitespace

hello world ↩
           ^
         cursor
```

So, you can simply define a macro that:

- first calls `fixup-whitespace`
- then removes the last whitespace

Another one could be `M-x replace-regexp RET [ ]+' RET ' RET`, which solves the problem using regular expressions.

Comment: Note that the apostrophe is not really part of his problem, so your advice about the regex is technically incorrect.  s/'/$/ and it's right, though.

Comment: Please note that the original question contained apostrophes.

Answer (score 53):

There is an emacs command `delete-trailing-whitespace` that gets rid of whitespace after last character. If you run it without any region marked, it cleans up the whole buffer. If you have an active region, only the lines in the region are cleaned.

A lot of people add the following code to their `.emacs`, so that whenever they save a file, all trailing whitespace is cleaned up:

```
(add-hook 'before-save-hook
          'delete-trailing-whitespace)
```

Comment: And if the point is inside a string of whitespaces and if you want to remove all of them then `M-\ ` will do the trick.

Comment: I have forgotten the name of this and for some reasons couldn't find it - thanks! 

Answer (score 2):

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DeletingWhitespace has all you need to know.

This one is quick and works in all Emacs versions:

`M-x picture-mode`, then <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I know you've already got an answer, but in addtion to `fixup-whitespace` there is also `delete-horizontal-whitespace` which deletes all of the whitespace around point. There are a couple of other related commands that are useful in various situations. You can look them up with `M-: (info "(elisp) User-Level Deletion")`.